# Xcode 6.0.1 check option is not highlighting after install?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

I Updated Xcode 5.1.1 to Xcode 6.0.1 and Suddenly check out option is not highlighting under source control.

I Installed all Xcode components, iPhone simulators and Library docs but still its not highlighting so I am not able to checkout.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered doing check out from terminal?

Comment: No,I am familiar with Xcode for Checkout,Commit and Push.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem when I install the latest Xcode 6. I solved the my problem with setting the source control management preferences.

Set preferences for managing source control using the Source Control Management preferences pane.

Steps:
 1) In Xcode, choose Xcode > Preferences, and select Source Control.

2) In the pane that appears, select the  "Enable Source Control" check mark.  Enabling source   control turns on all source control management features within Xcode.
[image: You can find the attached screenshot for your reference.]